# Is sharding simply horizontal partitioning across multiple databases?

Tags: mysql, sql-server, database, partitioning, sharding

Ok i've got a bit of confusion between the terms **horizontal partitioning** and **sharding**.

Is **sharding** simply **horizontal partitioning** across multiple databases?

Answer (score 4):

In short, yes. Longer answer: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shard_%28database_architecture%29

Comment: That's funny because from that article I got "In short no"

Comment: "Database sharding is a method of horizontal partitioning in a database". Seems clear enough to me.  There'd be no point in sharding within a single database server.

Comment: I was thinking about the section 
"Shards compared to horizontal partitioning" that's wikipedia for you